# Symfony2 minor bug with fonts in production

Tags: css, symfony, production-environment

When I moved my project to production I have this minor bug, thats kiling me... I have no idea how to fix it.

The problem is simple. When I switch to production my fonts are a little different, they have slightly larger padding, larger font-size, and its all in bold.... I have no idea the reason for that.

The console does not show any css or js erros.

All files are the same.. Why can this happen?

Clearing cache and etc does not help. And yes, I dumed my assets in prod environment.

Comment: What do you use ? Bootstrap, Foundation, SASS, Compass, LESS ? Do you have change your navigator or clear cache navigator ?

Comment: I use bootstrap. I dont change any navigators